# Google Sheets - Equivalent of a FOR loop

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum

```
A1 = 8
A2 = 14
```

I don't know if an equivalent for this exists in Google Sheets but what I am trying to do is that for every multiple of 5 in `A1` I want to subtract 5 off of `A2` and make it one string in `A3`. So in this example `A3 = 14/9` And if `A1 = 12; A3 = 14/9/4` This should even go into the negatives in the case of `A1 = 16; A3 = 14/9/4/-1`

Ultimately I would like to avoid using the API/Script system if possible. Right now the only way I can think of doing it is a ton of `IF()` handlers.

This is the formula I am currently using, but understandably it's a mess and stops working when the `IF()`'s run out.

```
=A2&
  IF(A1>5, 
   "/"&A2-5&
   IF(A1>10, 
    "/"&A2-10&
    IF(A1>15, 
     "/"&A2-15&
     IF(A1>20, 
      "/"&A2-20
     , "")
    , "")
   , "")
  , "")
```

Comment: how did you get "14/9" division?

Comment: Because 14-5=9. I want to add each successive result to a single string separated by `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+1)),
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((     ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+2))<=
       TRANSPOSE(      ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+2))))*
      {A2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(5*-1&"♦",  QUOTIENT(A1, 5)), "♦"))}), 
 SIGN({A2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(5*-1&"♦",  QUOTIENT(A1, 5)), "♦"))})^2), 
 IFERROR(1/0)), "limit "&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)&" offset 1"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: running total mod

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but with a few tweaks it works. I tweaked it to `=A2&if(A1>5, "/"&JOIN(...Stuff...), "")` for some proper formatting in the way I wanted but it otherwise works great. Thanks very much, I'll leave the question up until later to see what else rolls in but right now this looks like the best answer.

Comment: Which is a good response, until I've gotten in trouble in this community for marking answers as correct too soon. So now I prefer to wait at least day.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
=A2-QUOTIENT(A1, 5)*5
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That gave me the final result. I will add a clarification of the formula I am currently using to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(JOIN("/", 
                   IF(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+1)),
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((    ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+2))<=
       TRANSPOSE(     ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&QUOTIENT(A1, 5)+2))))*
      {A2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(5*-1&"♣", QUOTIENT(A1, 5)), "♣"))}), 
 SIGN({A2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(5*-1&"♣", QUOTIENT(A1, 5)), "♣"))})^2), 
 IFERROR(1/0))))))
```

[image: 0]